# Print Second set of values using function call in Jquery custom ui dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using a jquery custom dialog box to print a set of values on a webpage.User clicks on a button and enters a set of five values in a custom dialog box and then these values are printed on the webpage.

I want to add a functionality where user has got the option to print another set of values if he wants.For this a radio button is given.Onclick another button will appear.On clicking this button user will be able to enter another set of five values which will also  be printed on the webpage along with the initial values..

The problem i'm facing is that I am able to print the first Five values,but when i click on the second button to enter 2nd set of values the pop up custom dialog box is takes in only one value even though i have called the function which was used to print the first set of values.The cnt variable is not getting reinitialized as expected as it is starting from 5 and not 1 as required..

Please help..

HTML code..

```
          <!doctype html>
          <html lang="en">
          <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
          <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
          <script>
          $(document).ready(function ()
           {   
              $('#dialog').dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              width: 250,
              height: 180,
              modal : true,
          resizable: false,
          show:"slow"
               });

      $('#dialog1').dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              width: 250,
              height: 180,
              modal : true,
        resizable: false,
         show:"slow"
               });
        $('#put').click(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
              });

        $('#but1').click(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
             });
            });

           function getPdata( arg ) {
            var f = document.getElementById( 'pForm' );
            close();
            return;
               }

            function close(){
             $( "#dialog" ).dialog( 'close' );
             }

             var cnt=1;
              function getPdata1() {
              var f = document.getElementById( 'pForm' );
              //var n1= f.name.value.toString();
              var n = $("input[name='name']").val();

              alert(n.length);
             if (n.length <= 10) {
           $('<div />',{id:"div" + cnt }).html(n).appendTo('body');  //crated div will have  id as `div`+ count;
        } else {
          alert('the data you have enterd is not in limit.Please try again');
         return;

        }
        close();
       if (cnt < 5) {
         f.name.value = "";
          $("#dialog").dialog('open');
          cnt++;
       }

        }

    function show()
         {
         document.getElementById("but1").style.visibility="visible";    

          }


         </script>
         </head>
         <body>

           <div>
             <button type="button" id="put" >Insert data</button>
             </div>

           <div id="dialog" title="Input Data">
           <form id="pForm" >
     name:<input type="text" name="name" width='50' height='100' maxlength="10" /><br> 
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="getPdata1()" />
     <input type="button" value="cancel" onclick="getPdata( this.value )" />
      </form>
      </div>

    <input type="radio" name="option" value="11" id="but"onclick="show()">Set 2<br>


    <button type="button" id="but1" style="visibility:hidden" >Insert data 2</button>

     <div id="dialog1" title="Input Data">
     <form id="pForm1" >
    name: <input type="text" name="name1" width='50' height='100' maxlength="10"/><br>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="getPdata1()" />
      <input type="button" value="cancel" onclick="getPdata( this.value )" />
      </form>
      </div>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('#but1').click(function() {
    cnt = 1; //reset the count here
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

Demo: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/udtCsi39miA2UFqCq0am?p=preview)